# Python Requests Module to send sequential post requests

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests

There are 2 forms. The urls of both forms are different. 
1st is : mobileSearch.jsp
2nd is : mobileModify.jsp

On 1st form i need to provide ctn and click on submit.After that i will get 2nd form where i will have to provide some text fields let's say username.

Now the issue is i'm sending POST req to 1st form and getting proper response but i am not clear on how to use this response and send another POST req to update some text field.

I suppose i need to use Sessions module but not clear on its use.

I have been searching the net for the past few days but didn't find anything useful. Any help regarding this would be appreciated?

Below is my code. Its not giving any error but its also not updating the value of parameter "paramName1".

```
import requests

proxy = {'http':'http://myhost:myport','https':'http://myhost:myport'}

url = 'myUrl'
data = {'paramName':'paramValue'}

s = requests.session()
s.auth = ('uname', 'pswd')
s.proxies = (proxy)
s.post(url, data=data)

data1 = {'paramName1':'paramValue1'}
url1 = 'myUrlNew'

s.post(url1, data=data1)
```

Comment: I typed `python session requests` into google and got the [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: I have been reading that doc for the past few hours Peter...but couldn't succeed in my attempt..

Comment: Post your failed attempt, what you thought it should do, what actually happened, then we can help you. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I have just now added my code. Could you please have a look at it?Its not giving any error but its also not updating the value of parameter "paramName1"

Comment: `Session` will help you automatically store cookies between requests but it won't do much else in your case with forms. My guess is that after the first `s.post(...)` you get a response, maybe a redirect to a new url. This new url might contain additional parameters (`jsession`/`id`/other token) and might not be exactly what you hardcoded in `url1 = '...'`. Or maybe it has the second form but with additional/hidden fields. If you can test your interaction manually in Chrome, check dev tools to see what is the request-response sequence, inspecting form submissions in exact detail.

Comment: The referer of 2nd jsp page is 1st jsp page...and also both the forms have different param fields...but i just want to update one param field in 2nd form...

Comment: I have retried with below code now...somewhere on StackOverflow i found that session object manages cookies transparently and i first need to get the form so that session id gets set and then post data there :url1 and url are 2 diff urls                                                                                `s = requests.session()
s.auth = ('uname', 'pswd')
s.proxies = (proxy)
s.get(url)
r = s.post(url, data=data)
header = {'Referer':r.url}
r1 = s.post(url1, data1, headers=header)`

Comment: @zxxc...i'm already using Session object..in that case i don't think i need to take care of jsessionid explicitly...Session object will take care of it, won't it?

Comment: I'm getting this error :- `This exception captures, detail infomation: null <br/> click BACK to re-enter<br/>`